# OpenCV: Camera Pose Estimation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I try to match two overlapping images captured with a camera. To do this, I'd like to use OpenCV. I already extracted the features with the `SurfFeatureDetector`. Now I try to to compute the rotation and translation vector between the two images.

As far as I know, I should use `cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2()`. Unfortunately, this method require `objectPoints` as an argument. These `objectPoints` are the world coordinates of the extracted features. These are not known in the current context.

Can anybody give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem of simultaneously computing relative pose between two images and the unknown 3d world coordinates has been treated here:

Berthold K. P. Horn. Relative orientation revisited. Berthold K. P. Horn. Artificial Intelligence Laboratory, Massachusetts Institute of Technology, 545 Technology ...

EDIT: here is a link to the paper:
http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.64.4700

Please see my answer to a related question where I propose a solution to this problem:

[OpenCV extrinsic camera from feature points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140924/opencv-extrinsic-camera-from-feature-points/8192775#8192775)

EDIT: You may want to take a look at bundle adjustments too,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_adjustment

That assumes an *initial estimate* is available.

**EDIT:** I found some code resources you might want to take a look at:

**Resource I:**

> http://www.maths.lth.se/vision/downloads/
>
> Two View Geometry Estimation with Outliers
>
> C++ code for finding the relative orientation of two calibrated
>   cameras in presence of outliers. The obtained solution is optimal in
>   the sense that the number of inliers is maximized.

**Resource II:**

> http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/src/ Relative orientation from
>   5 points: a somewhat more polished C routine implementing the minimal
>   solution for relative orientation of two calibrated cameras from
>   unknown 3D points. 5 points are required and there can be as many as
>   10 feasible solutions (but 2-5 is more common). Also requires a few
>   CLAPACK routines for linear algebra. There's also a short technical
>   report on this (included with the source).

**Resource III:**

> http://www9.in.tum.de/praktika/ppbv.WS02/doc/html/reference/cpp/toc_tools_stereo.html
>   vector_to_rel_pose        Compute the relative orientation between two
>   cameras given image point correspondences and known camera parameters
>   and reconstruct 3D space points.

Answer (score 2):

There is a theoretical solution, however, the OpenCV implementation of camera pose estimation lacks the needed tools.

The theoretical approach:
Step 1: extract the homography (the matrix describing the geometrical transform between images). use findHomography()
Step 2. Decompose the result matrix into rotations and translations. Use cv::solvePnP();

Problem: findHomography() returns a 3x3 matrix, corresponding to a projection from a plane to another. solvePnP() needs a 3x4 matrix, representing the 3D rotation/translation of the objects. I think that with some approximations, you can modify the solvePnP to give you some results, but it requires a lot of math and a very good understanding of 3D geometry.

Read more about at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Comment: The images will be related by a homography if (i) The only difference in pose is rotation about the camera centre _or_ (ii) Both images depict a planar object filling the whole image plane. In general, a homography does not model the transformation between the images.

Comment: What you describe here is an affine transform. A homography is a general transform from any 3D position to any other 3D position. It is completely described by a 4x4 matrix. However, if you apply some constrains to the transform (like all of them should stay in the same plane) you can use only a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant the 3x3 homography matrix that relates 2d image points represented with homogenous coordinates between the two images.

Comment: Homography assumes that all points lie on the same plane, which might not be the case here. As for the rotation and translation - you can compute the fundamental matrix (cv::findFundamentalMat()), calculate the essential matrix (cv::findEssentialMat()) and decompose the second using SVD plus a couple of additional steps (see book "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Visions" by Hartley and Zisserman) in order to get those.

Comment: Homography will only work if you are testing points on a plane. Or the motion is purely rotational. Otherwise you will have to use the essential matrix to extract the relative pose