# Sift Extraction - opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, surf, feature-extraction

I'm trying to get started working with sift feature extraction using (C++) OpenCv. I need to extract features using SIFT, match them between the original image (e.g. a book) and a scene, and after that calculate the camera pose.

So far I have found [this algorithm](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html) using SURF. Does anyone know a base code from which I can get started, or maybe a way to convert the algorithm in the link from SURF to SIFT?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Ok, I worked out a solution for the sift problem. Now I'm trying to figure the camera pose. I'm trying to use: solvePnP, can anyone help me with an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [feature2d tutorial section](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html) of the new OpenCV docs website.
There tutorials with code showing:

1. [Feature detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection) with e.g. SURF
2. [Feature Description](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html)
3. [Feature Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher)

Comment: Thanks, but this examples are for SURF. I need SIFT, or someway to convert a algorithm from SURF to SIFT.

Answer (score 4):

If you have managed to find matches between the image and the scene, then I suggest you apply cv::findHomography(). It will calculate the homography matrix using 4 matches as input.

You can convert to camera pose from the homography matrix directly.

Answer (score 0):

For using SIFT instead of SURF, I changed `SurfFeatureDetector` to `SiftFeatureDetector` and `SurfDescriptorExtractor` to `SiftDescriptorExtractor`. For some images, I found that the combination SURF detector <--> SIFT descriptor yields relatively accurate results, but you should experiment with other combinations (FAST detector - FREAK descriptor or ORB detector - BRISK descriptor), depending on your requirements.

Please follow this tutorial for solving the homography part of your question:
[Feature Matching and Homography](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography)

Also, maybe this will help: [Pose Estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140924/opencv-extrinsic-camera-from-feature-points/8192775#8192775)